# Issue with length of string value

Tags: string, memory

I have been getting some weird issues with a sketch I put together(apart from memory low warnings, it was working fine)

When im about to post data to my php server - it seems not all the information is available

eg the output will be

```
42399.92
&HAAlt=-18.24
```

Is there a limit to string length?

Im crudely constructing a string to send to a post request

```
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Ethernet.h>
#include "DHT.h"
#include <math.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include "MutichannelGasSensor.h"
#include "HP20x_dev.h"
#include "KalmanFilter.h"

unsigned char ret = 0;

/* Instance */
KalmanFilter t_filter;    //temperature filter
KalmanFilter p_filter;    //pressure filter
KalmanFilter a_filter;    //altitude filter

// Enter a MAC address for your controller below.
// Newer Ethernet shields have a MAC address printed on a sticker on the shield
byte mac[] = { 0xDE, 0xAD, 0xBE, 0xEF, 0xFE, 0xED };
// if you don't want to use DNS (and reduce your sketch size)
// use the numeric IP instead of the name for the server:
IPAddress server(192, 168, 0, 30); // numeric IP for Google (no DNS)
//char server[] = "www.google.com";    // name address for Google (using DNS)

// Set the static IP address to use if the DHCP fails to assign
IPAddress ip(192, 168, 0, 40);

// Initialize the Ethernet client library
// with the IP address and port of the server
// that you want to connect to (port 80 is default for HTTP):
EthernetClient client;


#define Vc 4.95
//the number of R0 you detected just now
#define R0 35.54
#define DHTPIN A1     // what pin we're connected to

// Uncomment whatever type you're using!
//#define DHTTYPE DHT11   // DHT 11
#define DHTTYPE DHT22   // DHT 22  (AM2302)
//#define DHTTYPE DHT21   // DHT 21 (AM2301)

DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

int pin = 8;
unsigned long duration;
unsigned long starttime;
unsigned long sampletime_ms = 2000;//sampe 30s&nbsp;;
unsigned long lowpulseoccupancy = 0;
float ratio = 0;
float concentration = 0;
String data;
String data2;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while (!Serial) {
    ; // wait for serial port to connect. Needed for native USB port only
  }

  delay(150);
  HP20x.begin();
  delay(100);

  /* Determine HP20x_dev is available or not */
  ret = HP20x.isAvailable();
  if (OK_HP20X_DEV == ret)
  {
    Serial.println("HP20x_dev is available.\n");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("HP20x_dev isn't available.\n");
  }

  pinMode(8, INPUT);
  starttime = millis();//get the current time;
  Serial.println("power on!");


  pinMode(4, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(4, HIGH);

  //if (Ethernet.begin(mac) == 0) {
  //  Serial.println("Failed to configure Ethernet using DHCP");
  // try to congifure using IP address instead of DHCP:
  Ethernet.begin(mac, ip);

  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  delay(10000);
  Serial.println("connecting...");
  //}
  // give the Ethernet shield a second to initialize:
  //delay(1000);
  //Serial.println("connecting...");



  // Serial.println(Ethernet.localIP());


  gas.begin(0x04);//the default I2C address of the slave is 0x04
  gas.powerOn();
  //Serial.print("Firmware Version = ");
  //Serial.println(gas.getVersion());
  //Serial.println("Particles\tRS\tHCHO (PPM)\tNH3 (PPM)\tCO (PPM)\tNO2 (PPM)\tC3H8 (PPM)\tC4H10 (PPM)\tCH4 (PPM)\tH2 (PPM)\tC2H5OH (PPM)");
  dht.begin();
  delay(10000);

  data = "";
  data2 = "";
}

void loop() {

  if (client.available()) {
    char c = client.read();
    Serial.print(c);
  }

  float HATemp2;
  float HAPres2;
  float HAAlt2;

  if (OK_HP20X_DEV == ret)
  {
    long HATemp = HP20x.ReadTemperature();
    float p = HATemp / 100.0;
    HATemp2 = t_filter.Filter(p);

    long HAPres = HP20x.ReadPressure();
    p = HAPres / 100.0;
    HAPres2 = p_filter.Filter(p);

    long HAAlt = HP20x.ReadAltitude();
    p = HAAlt / 100.0;
    HAAlt2 = a_filter.Filter(p);

  }

  duration = pulseIn(pin, LOW);
  lowpulseoccupancy = lowpulseoccupancy + duration;

  float d;

  if ((millis() - starttime) >= sampletime_ms) //if the sampel time = = 30s
  {
    ratio = lowpulseoccupancy / (sampletime_ms * 10.0); // Integer percentage 0=&gt;100

    d = 1.1 * pow(ratio, 3) - 3.8 * pow(ratio, 2) + 520 * ratio + 0.62; // using spec sheet curve
    //Serial.print("concentration = ");

    lowpulseoccupancy = 0;
    starttime = millis();
  }
  //Serial.print("\t");
  //HCHO

  int sensorValue = analogRead(A0);
  double Rs = (1023.0 / sensorValue) - 1;

  double ppm = pow(10.0, ((log10(Rs / R0) - 0.0827) / (-0.4807)));
  //Serial.print("HCHO ppm = ");

  //MultiChannel Gas
  float NH3 = gas.measure_NH3();
  float CO = gas.measure_CO();
  float NO2 = gas.measure_NO2();
  float C3H8 = gas.measure_C3H8();
  float C4H10 = gas.measure_C4H10();
  float CH4 = gas.measure_CH4();
  float H2 = gas.measure_H2();
  float C2H5OH = gas.measure_C2H5OH();


  // Reading temperature or humidity takes about 250 milliseconds!
  // Sensor readings may also be up to 2 seconds 'old' (its a very slow sensor)
  float h = dht.readHumidity();
  float t = dht.readTemperature();

  data = String("dust=") + d + "&rs=" + Rs + "&hcho=" + ppm + "&nh3=" + NH3 + "&co=" + CO + "&no2=" + NO2 + "&c3h8=" + C3H8 + "&c4h10=" + C4H10 + "&ch4=" + CH4;
  data2 = String("&h2=") + H2 + "&c2h5oh=" + C2H5OH + "&temp=" + t + "&hum=" + h + "&HATemp=" + HATemp2 + "&HAPres=" + HAPres2 + "&HAAlt=" + HAAlt2;

  Serial.println(data);
  Serial.println(data2);


  if (client.connect(server, 80)) {
    Serial.println("connected");
    client.println("POST /air_add.php HTTP/1.1");
    client.println("Host:  192.168.0.30");
    client.println("User-Agent: Arduino/1.0");
    client.println("Connection: close");
    client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;");
    client.print("Content-Length: ");
    client.println(data.length());
    client.println();
    client.println(data);
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("could not connect");
  }

  if (client.connected()) {
    client.stop();
  }

  Serial.println("done.");

  delay(30000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a real limit on the length of a String that you are running into.  But when you are running low on RAM (the low memory warnings you mentioned) then there is a limit on how much memory you have to put that String before you cause memory corruption and either crash the program or at best get some weird output.

The String class is particularly wasteful of memory and it has some issues when using the + operator to concatenate Strings that will leave the heap memory full of holes and reduce the amount of memory you have even further.  On memory constrained systems like microcontrollers, the String class crutch is a thing to be avoided.  Learn to use char arrays and real c-style strings and you'll be better off.

One place you could immediately save some memory would be by putting all the constant strings in your code into PROGMEM instead of leaving them out in RAM.  So this:

```
client.println("Connection: close");
client.println("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;");
```

becomes

```
client.println(F("Connection: close"));
client.println(F("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded;"));
```

Comment: It was memory!! thank you - I did as suggested and it had a huge impact on usage

Comment: output is now dust=0.62&rs=12.29&hcho=13.54&nh3=2.71&co=13.67&no2=0.78&c3h8=4579.24&c4h10=2334.79&ch4=42399.92&h2=4.14&c2h5oh=7.25&temp=23.20&hum=65.90&HATemp=11.52&HAPres=507.68&HAAlt=-8.82
 :)

Comment: Is that good or bad?

Comment: It’s good. That’s the full list of sensor data

Answer (score 2):

There is no limit for String other than the available memory. No String can be longer that ~2KB.

In these statments

```
data = String("dust=") + d + "&rs=" + Rs + "&hcho=" + ppm + "&nh3=" + NH3 + "&co=" + CO + "&no2=" + NO2 + "&c3h8=" + C3H8 + "&c4h10=" + C4H10 + "&ch4=" + CH4;
data2 = String("&h2=") + H2 + "&c2h5oh=" + C2H5OH + "&temp=" + t + "&hum=" + h + "&HATemp=" + HATemp2 + "&HAPres=" + HAPres2 + "&HAAlt=" + HAAlt2;
```

you are creating and deleting a lot of temporary Strings. How much memory will you need to hold all those temp Strings togheter? You don't know. Hard to say, because it's implementation dependent.

In Arduino you have to learn to use `char` arrays (and pointers) to works with strings. With a low level C method you know exactly how much space you will need. If you don't have enough memory, you still can reorganize your sketch to work around limitations.

Arduino is a low level world.

Comment: +1  - I will investigate optimisation via char arrays